# Swapping vector of pointers to objects to output swapped objects

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

So I'm supposed to be using bubble sort to swap a vector of objects using a vector of pointers pointing to each element of that vector of objects. I successfully sorted a vector of objects but I would like to swap the vector of pointers to sort the vector of objects (the requirement for the assignment). I tried the below code to swap the pointers.

```
void BubSort(vector<List*> & vect, unsigned sortWay) {
            switch (sortWay) {
            case 2:
                if (vect[j]->GetId() > vect[j + 1]->GetId()) {
                    BubSortMeth(vect[j], vect[j + 1]);
                } break;
            case 3:
                if (vect[j]->GetName() > vect[j + 1]->GetName()) {
                    BubSortMeth(vect[j], vect[j + 1]);
                } break;
            case 4:
                if (vect[j]->GetQuant() > vect[j + 1]->GetQuant()) {
                    BubSortMeth(vect[j], vect[j + 1]);
                } break;
            case 5: 
                if (vect[j]->GetPrice() > vect[j + 1]->GetPrice()) {
                    BubSortMeth(vect[j], vect[j + 1]);
                } break;
            }
        }
    }
};
void BubSortMeth(List *lhs, List *rhs) {
    List * temp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = temp;
}
```

I'm using the below code to create my vector of objects and the vector of pointers to each object in that vector

```
    while (fin >> tempVect) {           // input to temp List first then iterate through vector to set variables
        vectList.push_back(tempVect);
        vectList[i].SetId(tempVect.GetId());
        vectList[i].SetName(tempVect.GetName());
        vectList[i].SetQuant(tempVect.GetQuant());
        vectList[i].SetPrice(tempVect.GetPrice());
        if (vectList[i].GetPrice() < 0 || vectList[i].GetQuant() < 0) {
            vectList.erase(vectList.begin() + (i));
        }
        else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vectList.size(); i++)
    {
        pointVectList.push_back(&vectList[i]);
    }
```

The output shows the unsorted vector of objects. If each element in the pointer vector is pointing to its respective element in the same index of the object pointer, shouldn't swapping the vector of pointers swap the vector of objects?

Comment: You really should provide a [mcve].  If you did that, you would see [the same issue as here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dffd3cf36800dca).  Also, what you're doing is usually done by using a vector of simple `int` indices, not with pointers.  The assignment given to you is more convoluted than it should be by using pointers.

Comment: Replace callsites of `BubSortMeth` with `std::swap`.  The `BubSortMeth` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: *shouldn't swapping the vector of pointers swap the vector of objects?* -- One vector has nothing to do with the other vector.  You can swap that pointer vector all you want -- the original `vectList` is not affected.  If you want to see the sorted list, you have to use the pointer vector.

Comment: Whether or not your output should be sorted depends on how you print it (possibly also on how you call `BubSort`). Perhaps you could focus more on these aspects and less on the bubble sort? Try a simpler case where you hardcode two elements to put in your vectors. Then swap the elements on one vector and output the result. At the moment, you should test if you can change the order of elements; whether or not they end up sorted or not is a separate question (the next question, probably).